# Prolems with DataProtection API (C#)

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, data-protection

I have an Azure WebApp with multiple deployment slots.
I want each deployment slot to have it's own data protection key.
The key should persist between deployments.

```
Uri storageUri = new Uri(blobStorageSasUri);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(storageUri);
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("identityserver4dataprotectionkeys");
container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName($"{_env.EnvironmentName}_identityserver4")
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, $"{_env.EnvironmentName}/dataprotectionkeys.xml");
```

Strangly, the application searches for other keys than are present in the blob storage. E.g. this exception:

```
CryptographicException: The key {3c2e44fa-dbeb-4547-8d1d-40f5eed15590} was not found in the key ring.
```

While in the blob storage I have key id: 6bed1559-9bf7-42af-83fd-85fb417c4edc.

Also the blob storage always has only one key present.

I have real troubles implementing this API.. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixen this by Using keyvault.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("<blobUriWithSasToken>"))
    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault("<keyIdentifier>", "<clientId>",         "<clientSecret>");
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#protectkeyswithazurekeyvault

Comment: Tried with AzureKeyVault but in the blob storage there is still the unencrypted key. Seems that the key update doesn't work right.

Comment: Had to allow "wrap" and "unwrap" key in policies

Comment: I also had to delete the old (unpreocted) blob storage. Now I have keys protected with azure key vault that are working so far. The lifetime is 1 day altough I set `.SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14))`. But this may be because of my own DataProtectorTokenProvider I set up to be able to debug what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that 3c2e44fa-dbeb-4547-8d1d-40f5eed15590 is present in a blog storage belong to another environment? Can you check if EnvironmentName returns the expected value?